# Using slideUp() and remove() on more than one DIV

Tags: jquery, slideup

I have the following code which should find all the DIVs, except the first, within my table, slide them up and then remove them!

```
$("#myTable div:not(:first)").slideUp('slow', function() {
$(this).remove();
});
```

Now it successfully applies this to the second DIV but to no other.

However, if I use

```
$("#myTable div:not(:first)").slideUp('slow').remove();
```

it removes all the DIVs after the first correctly.  However, the slideUp animation does not run.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Show your html. My exaple with your jQuery code works good, check it on http://jsfiddle.net/aV4FT/

Comment: I cant really add any HTML.  What I can say is that the myTable DIV has one child div to begin with.  When a button is pressed this DIV clones, is given new a new ID and then inserts after the last DIV.  The slideUp and remove only seem to do one at a time and it's always to the first DIV after the original.  Thanks

Comment: I see now. You need to put your code (your code example is proper) after all elements are already cloned, for example in callback method.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example? Thanks

Comment: Instead of a click, the divs should slideup when a certain option is selected in a dropdown.  i've changed your code to .change and still it only slides up one clone! Help! :-(

Comment: Strange it works fine with selectbox for me, please check this update http://jsfiddle.net/aV4FT/2/ I guest you have some problem with code wich clones your divs.

Comment: Anyway I can't give you more help, without knowing your HTML and JS logic. The problem is in something else, not in question you provided.

Comment: I finally got it.  I had .clone(true).  For some reason this stopped it working.  Thanks for everyones help, especially Arthur!

Answer (score 3):

Yep - you need to remove AFTER the slide up has completed. Like so:

```
$("#myTable div:not(:first)").slideUp('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that your first example should work. See this fiddle as an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/qWjnt/